# js-render if construction with parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsrender

I call my template like this:

```
$("#ChangeCurrentCycleDiv").html(
        $("#UpdateTemplate").render(CurrentCyclefields,
                {ButtonName: "btnChangeCycle",
                 Titel: "Change Current Cycle",
                 FormID: "ChangeCurrentCycleForm",
                 PanelSize: "ms-Panel ms-Panel--Max" }, 
                true)
    );
```

This worked fine but now I added the "PanelSize" parameter which sometimes is used and sometimes is not. So in my template I try to do this:

```
<div {{if {{:~PanelSize}} }} class={{:~PanelSize}} {{else}}class="ms-Panel ms-Panel--xxl"{{/if}}>
```

But what kind of variant I use, it's not working (wrong syntax errors).

What is the correct syntax to do this? So if the parameter is send, it is used. Otherwise the default is used.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax for `{{if}}` is `{{if ~PanelSize}} .... {{else}} ... {{if}}`

http://www.jsviews.com/#iftag

So in your case  it would be

```
<div {{if ~PanelSize}}class="{{:~PanelSize}}"{{else}}class="ms-Panel ms-Panel--xxl"{{/if}}>
```

Or better, perhaps:

```
<div class="{{if ~PanelSize}}{{:~PanelSize}}{{else}}ms-Panel ms-Panel--xxl{{/if}}">
```

Alternatively you can use ternary expressions:

```
<div class="{{:~PanelSize?~PanelSize:'ms-Panel ms-Panel--xxl'}}">
```

or even simpler with a `||`

```
<div class="{{:~PanelSize||'ms-Panel ms-Panel--xxl'}}">
```

If you are using JsViews data-linking, you can instead use a data-linked expression:

```
<div data-link="class{:~PanelSize||'ms-Panel ms-Panel--xxl'}">
```